# Validating adb2c jwt is throwing Invalid authorization token: InvalidSignatureError in Python

Tags: python, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have been trying to validate a jwt received from adb2c in Python in the latest days. For that case, I use the `azure_ad_verify_token` library and have followed a tutorial on their docs page. As they say, I define

```
azure_ad_app_id = "app_id"
azure_ad_issuer = f"https://login.***.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0"
azure_ad_jwks_uri = f"https://login.***.com/{tenant_id}/discovery/v2.0/keys"
token = "eyJ0...."

payload = verify_jwt(
    token=token,
    valid_audiences=[azure_ad_app_id],
    issuer=azure_ad_issuer,
    jwks_uri=azure_ad_jwks_uri,
    verify=True,
)
```

However, this code throws me an error that says

> Invalid authorization token: InvalidSignatureError in Python

I'm not sure why does this error happen because the same token is validated successfully in .NET but it fails in Python.

However, another thing I noticed is that if I paste the jwt at https://jwt.io/, I get a message at the end that says **Invalid Signature**. I went through the Internet and found that I need to pass my public key but even after passing it, I still get that same **Invalid Signature** message.

Has someone ever stumbled upon an error like this? Does this seem like a problem with the configuration of the token in b2c?

Comment: Do you see the same error when pasting the token on https://jwt.ms/ page?

Comment: No, there were no errors on jwt.ms

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *jwks_uri* parameter value is wrong. It should contain the name of the policy in the suffix:

https://tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1a_signinsignup

Please check and let me know.

Comment: I have tried it but I get the following error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Do you think that this situation might happen because of bad configuration?

Comment: Got it. Could you please tell if you use "user flows" or "custom policies" in the Azure AD B2C? Also could you provide the name of it?

Comment: I use user flows. The name of the flow is **B2C_1_signupsignin**

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that the header contains `nonce`. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388742/azure-active-directory-access-token-validation-fails, validation fails because `nonce` exists. Do you think this might be the cause?

Comment: I do not think that this is about the nonce but let's investigate. Could you please paste this URL in the browser to see if you are able to display information about keys? Replace "your-tenant-name" with the name of your specific AD B2C tenant:
https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=B2C_1_signupsignin

Comment: I replaced this but I face a different error now: the `kid` from my header couldn't be found in the list of `kids` from https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=B2C_1_signupsignin

Comment: Could you please try one more thing? Please set the following parameters:
azure_ad_issuer = https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/

jwks_uri = https://tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/discovery/v2.0/keys?p=b2c_1a_signinsignup

Then please test and let me know.

Comment: Still getting the `kid` error :/ In my opinion I don't think it's about azure_ad_issuer because I dived deeper into the jwt library from python and while debugging it doesn't include the issuer at all in the process. It fails when: decodes the header, gets a `kid` from the header, gets the jwk and looks for a `kid`, retrieved from the jwk url, that has the same value as the `kid` of the header.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the update. Hmm, let me investigate it - I will get back once I have any new updates.